# CSS columns that automatically relocate overflowing content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

In a `ul` element, is it possible to have list items automatically move to the right when overflowing? For example, say that there is an unordered list with a height of `300px`. The total height (border + padding + margin included) of a list element is 60px. If there are, say, 4 list elements, they are listed top to bottom. But is it possible to make extra list elements start on a new column? For example, if there were six, put one on a new column to the right? I have tried researching this, and found nothing. Maybe it has to do with `display`?

Comment: Don't think so, no. You could reformat the whole list with a nested list, like a menu...maybe...ow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the `ul` as a flex container with the settings shown below

```css
ul {
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla</li>
  <li>bla bla</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! And, I discovered that if you have a title and want the new column on the right of the title _too_, just make the `ul` tall enough to include the title, float the title, and put a transparent `li` under it.